# First attempt at Haskell: Converting lower case letters to upper case

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have recently started learning Haskell, and I've tried creating a function in order to convert a lower case word to an upper case word, it works, but I don't know how good it is and  I have some questions.
Code:

```
lowerToUpperImpl element list litereMari litereMici = 
 do
  if not (null  list) then
   if (head list) == element then
     ['A'..'Z'] !! (length ['A'..'Z'] - length (tail list ) -1)
   else
     lowerToUpperImpl element (tail list) litereMari litereMici
  else
    '0' --never to be reached

lowerToUpper element = lowerToUpperImpl element ['a'..'z'] ['A'..'Z'] ['a'..'z']

lowerToUpperWordImpl word  = 
 do 
  if not (null word) then
   lowerToUpper (head (word)):(lowerToUpperWordImpl (tail word))
  else
   ""
```

1. I don't like the way I have passed the upper case and lower case
   letters , couldn't I just declare a global variables or something?
2. What would your approach be in filling the dead else branch?

What would your suggestions on improving this be?

Comment: Perhaps this question should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I agree with Daniel, and will gladly give you an in depth discussion of the program if you put it there, however, let me just note here that you can convert strings to uppercase in Haskell with just "map toUpper".

Comment: Use pattern matching instead of `null` and `head`

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! I would gladly move it, but I don't know how (if that doesn't mean deleting it here and recreating it there). Anyway I will keep that in mind when posting future questions like this one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, if/else is generally seen as a crutch in functional programming languages, precisely because they aren't really supposed to be used as branch operations, but as functions. Also remember that lists don't know their own lengths in Haskell, and so calculating it is an `O(n)` step. This is particularly bad for infinite lists.

I would write it more like this (if I didn't import any libraries):

```
uppercase :: String -> String
uppercase = map (\c -> if c >= 'a' && c <= 'z' then toEnum (fromEnum c - 32) else c)
```

Let me explain. This code makes use of the `Enum` and `Ord` typeclasses that `Char` satisfies. `fromEnum c` translates `c` to its ASCII code and `toEnum` takes ASCII codes to their equivalent characters. The function I supply to `map` simply checks that the character is lowercase and subtracts 32 (the difference between 'A' and 'a') if it is, and leaves it alone otherwise.

Of course, you could always just write:

```
import Data.Char
uppercase :: String -> String
uppercase = map toUpper
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

The things I always recommend to people in your circumstances are these:

1. Break the problem down into smaller pieces, and write separate functions for each piece.
2. Use library functions wherever you can to solve the smaller subproblems.
3. As an exercise after you're done, figure out how to write on your own the library functions you used.

In this case, we can apply the points as follows.  First, since `String` in Haskell is a synonym for `[Char]` (list of `Char`), we can break your problem into these two pieces:

- Turn a character into its uppercase counterpart.
- Transform a list by applying a function separately to each of its members.

Second point: as Alex's answer points out, the `Data.Char` standard library module comes with a function [`toUpper`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/libraries/base/Data-Char.html#v%3atoUpper) that performs the first task, and the `Prelude` library comes with `map` which performs the second.  So using those two together solves your problem immediately (and this is exactly the code Alex wrote earlier):

```
import Data.Char
uppercase :: String -> String
uppercase = map toUpper
```

But I'd say that this is the best solution (shortest and clearest), and as a beginner, **this is the first answer you should try**.

Applying my third point: after you've come up with the standard solution, it is enormously educational to try and write your own versions of the library functions you used.  The point is that this way you learn three things:

1. How to break down problems into easier, smaller pieces, preferably reusable ones;
2. The contents of the standard libraries of the language;
3. How to write the simple "foundation" functions that the library provides.

So in this case, you can try writing your own versions of `toUpper` and `map`.  I'll provide a skeleton for `map`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f [] = ???
map f (x:xs) = ???
```

Comment: An analogy I like to use is that manual recursion is very similar to using a gotos (very flexible but also very low level) and using higher-order combinators like map is like using a structured for or while loop.